# Модель не проходит проверку is_valid()

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель бланка. Она должна создаваться в отдельной форме, но по какой-то причине не проходит проверку is_valid()   - (Если убрать, выдает ValueError). Есть предположение, что ошибка выдается из-за того, что не все поля заполняются (в моделе их 12, а в форме я заполняю 9), но остальные поля мне не нужны для заполнения, и они стоят с параметрами default="..." . Помогите!

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Blank(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=50)
    second_name = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=50)
    third_name = models.CharField("Отчество (если есть)", max_length=50, default='')
    email_addr = models.EmailField("email-адрес", unique=True)
    phone_num = models.CharField("Номер телефона", max_length=15, default="", unique=True)
    passport_id = models.CharField("Серия и номер паспорта", max_length=11, unique=True)
    age = models.DateField("Дата рождения", default=date(2002, 1, 1))
    registration_address = models.CharField("Адрес регистрации", max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField("Фото", default=None, upload_to='photos/')
    is_blank_valid = models.BooleanField("Заявление составлено правильно?", default=False)
    is_passport_reissue = models.BooleanField("Паспорт перевыпущен?", default=False)
    blank_date = models.DateField("дата оформления", default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.second_name + ' ' + self.first_name + ' ' + self.third_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "заявление"
        verbose_name_plural = "заявления"
```

```py
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Blank

class BlankForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blank
        fields = ["second_name", "first_name", "third_name", "email_addr", 
                  "phone_num", "passport_id", "age",
                  "registration_address", "blank_date", "photo"]
```

```py
# view.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from .forms import BlankForm


...

def blankCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blankform = BlankForm(request.POST)
        if blankform.is_valid():
            blankform.save()
            return redirect('dashboardView')
    else:
        blankform = BlankForm()
    return render(request, 'blankCreate.html', {'form': blankform})
```

```
# blankCreate.html
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block context %}
    <h1>Blank create system</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Фамилия: {{form.second_name}}</p>
        <p>Имя: {{form.first_name}}</p>
        <p>Отчество: {{form.third_name}}</p>
        <p>Эл. почта: {{form.email_addr}}</p>
        <p>Номер телефона: {{form.phone_num}}</p>
        <p>Серия и номер паспорта: {{form.passport_id}}</p>
        <p>Возраст: {{form.age}}</p>
        <p>Адрес регистрации: {{form.registration_address}}</p>
        <p>Фото: {{form.photo}}</p>
        <button>Create new blank</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Добавил к проверка валидности следующий кусок: `else: print(blankform.errors)` 
оказалось, что все-таки ошибка в том, что я не добавляю blank_data - её я сейчас просто убрал, ибо она заполняется сегодняшней датой, и не добавляю photo, что мне уже не понятно, ибо поле фото заполняется...

Comment: без photo все работает